# Identifying value in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a problem and then I need your help to solve it.

I have a matrix A

```
A = [ 0 0 1 2 3 4 0;
      1 2 3 4 0 0 0;
      0 0 0 1 2 3 4;
      0 1 2 3 4 0 0]
```

and then I want to know how many number of each values "1" of each rows in matrix A which is not in the same column with each value ">=3" of each rows in matrix A.

so I wish that my answer

```
Ans = 2
```

Thanks before.

Comment: So you want to find all the columns that have a 1 in it but not a value greater than 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
>> num = sum( any(A(:,all(A<3))==1,2) )
num =
     2
```

First we find the columns indices containing no values greater or equal to 3 `idx = all(A<3)`.

Next in those columns `A(:,idx)`, we find the rows containing any 1: `any(A(:,idx)==1,2)`.

Finally we count how many such rows were found `sum(.)`

Comment: you are right, though I don't see an improvement or significant difference to my answer 7 minutes before yours!?

Comment: Agreed - I do apologize for that, I downvoted it when I thought it was wrong, and apparently my downvote is locked in unless the answer gets edited.

Comment: @mutzmatron : mr, If matrix A is 3D matrix, how can I modify your code? i feel difficult to do it, thanks before.

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono - if `A` is a 3d matrix, your original question is not well defined. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @FebriDwiLaksono: just as with your other question, give us an example of input with 3D matrix and the expected output. Also for the future, it is always a good idea to state all your requirements in the question up-front.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
   sum( (sum(A == 1 ,1) > 0) & ~(sum(A >= 3,1) > 0))
```

Comment: @Perchik - I think that's what he meant though it was a bit confusing -  thanks for confirming that's what you thought too!