# How to identify value a matrix by considering others matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have some matrices here :

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 0 0 0;
      0 0 1 2 3 4 0]
B = [ 0 1 2 3 4 0 0;
      0 0 0 1 2 3 4]
C = [ 1 2 3 4 0 0 0;
      0 1 2 3 4 0 0]
```

and I call matrices above as "initial matrix". then I have "matrix D" here :

```
D = [ 1 2 3 4 0 0 0;
      1 2 3 4 0 0 0]
```

where I have to identify how many are value "1" in each row in matrix D which is not the same column with value ">3" in each row in matrix A,B,C which had been rearranged like the following example here.

```
1 2 3 4 0 0 0
0 0 1 2 3 4 0
    0 1 2 3 4 0 0 
    0 0 0 1 2 3 4
        1 2 3 4 0 0 0
        0 1 2 3 4 0 0 

            1 2 3 4 0 0 0
            1 2 3 4 0 0 0
```

and I wish my answer is 0, because value 1 for first and second row in the matrix D is the same column with one of some value in same column with value 1 which has value > 3 (4).

what is code to make answer like that guys? please help me, thanks before.

Comment: @EitanT: what did you mean, sir?

Comment: @EitanT: I had accepted answer of my last question sir, then please help me to solve this problem sir.

Comment: @EitanT : ouh I forgot to accept your answer, thanks you so much for your answer sir before. :)

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your current question, can you give another few more examples where the answer is non-zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start with a simple solution. Please confirm if this is the intended behavior:

First we arrange the matrices A,B,C,D as you've shown:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 0 0 0;
      0 0 1 2 3 4 0];
B = [ 0 1 2 3 4 0 0;
      0 0 0 1 2 3 4];
C = [ 1 2 3 4 0 0 0;
      0 1 2 3 4 0 0];
D = [ 1 2 3 4 0 0 0;
      1 2 3 4 0 0 0];

X = zeros(8,13);
X(1:2,1:7) = A;
X(3:4,3:9) = B;
X(5:6,5:11) = C;
X(7:8,7:13) = D;
```

which gives us:

```
X =
     1     2     3     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     2     3     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     2     3     4     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     3     4     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     2     3     4     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     3     4     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     3     4     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     3     4     0     0     0
```

Now we can re-use answers from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11653887/97160) to do the counting:

```
numPerRow = sum(X(7:8,all(X(1:6,:)<4))==1,2)
num = sum(numPerRow)
```

both rows of the matrix `D` give zeros, thus the total sum is also zero:

```
numPerRow =
     0
     0

num =
     0
```